# LINQ Select Many question

Tags: linq-to-sql, select, linq

Can you use SelectMany in a query against your DB and if you can, what type does the column need to be in order to do this?  I am messing around with LINQPad and anytime I try to use SelectMany I get an error, and from what I am reading it sounds like the type in your lambda expression has to be a collection.

Comment: Can you provide the things you've tried, the respective error messages, and what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Houses.SelectMany(h => h.HousesPersons.Select(hp => hp.Person.Name))
```

If you have 3 Tables. Houses, HousesPersons and Persons. 
Houses  has a One->Many relationship with Persons using HousesPersons to store HouseId and PersonId.

This query will get you a list of all persons in all houses in a flat list, rather than grouped by House.

EDIT: Sorry I can't get AdventureWorks to work on my machine to use a text book example.

Comment: Great explanation.  But in order to do that, do you always need with multiple table? Is there no way to just say Houses.SelectMany(some lambda expression)?

Comment: Why would you need to, does Select not return the data you need? Unless the result of your Select() returned IEnumerable<IEnumberable<T>> - or other structured data. You only need to use SelectMany() to flatten out your data.

Answer (score 0):

`SelectMany` projects each element of a sequence (i.e. a property of an object that is an enumeration or list) into an `IEnumerable<T>` and flattens the resulting sequence of sequences into a single sequence / `IEnumerable<T>`.

Having said that it could be applicable in i.e. a Linq to Entities environment - you could i.e. select select the navigation properties  (related entities) of multiple entities and spit them out in a single list.